# Option for plain text formatting of Rmarkdown chunk output?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

The output of Rmarkdown code chunks is formatted as R code using `knitr`. While this works fine for light themes (black font on white background), this behaviour is a pain for dark themes.
The example shows the 'Dracula' theme of the `highlight.js` library using the R package `reportMD`.

#### 1) Rmarkdown (reportMD)

````
---
output:
  reportMD::multi_document:
    toc: true
    fig_caption: true
    highlight: dracula 
params:
  version: !r 
---

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

````
```{r, results='asis'}
head(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

Desired colouring of R code chunks would equal plain markdown colouring:

````
```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```
````

[image]

However, for the R presentation package [`xaringan`](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan), also `highlight.js` is used for syntax highlighting. The engine behind `xaringan`  is [`remark.js`](https://github.com/gnab/remark). When evaluating R code chunks here, the R source is highlighted and the output is displayed as plain text.

#### 2) xaringan

````
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: dracula
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

[image]

I do not what is going on in detail behind the scenes (`xaringan` + `remark` vs. `knitr` + `rmarkdown`).
A wonderful option would be to have a chunk option to turn plain text code output on & off.
The desired output is 2)

Comment: As in `results='asis'`? `hightlight=FALSE`? Or `highlight` in the YAML front matter? You need to make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: @alistaire added code to reproduce it. Chunk option `results='asis'` does not render the output correctly. Btw: I would prefer critical comments/questions rather than direct closing votes...

Comment: "the desired output is 2" I don't understand, you want a dark theme but output 2, the image in the xarigan section has a white background?

Comment: @PaulRougieux I want either "white background with black font color" like in `xaringan` OR "black background with white font color" as in plain markdown code chunks using 'Dracula' theme. However, I only get bluish font color on black background when using R code chunks. Thats because the chunk output is formatted and coloured as R comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = "")` prevents `knitr` and `highlight.js` from formatting the chunk output as comments and therefore no comment colouring is applied.

[image]